# free string in the setter

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Do I need to free the previously allocated string within the setter?

```
static void setType(Employee *self, const char *type) {
    if(self->type) free(self->type);
    self->type = strdup(type);
}
```

**Edit**

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    char *type;
    void *data;
    void (*display)(Employee *self);
}

void release(Employee *self) {
    free(self->type); //  required?
    free(self->display); // required?
    self->data = NULL; // required?
    free(self); 
}
```

**Edit 2**

Do I need to free the function pointers?

```
void display(Employee *self) {
     // display employee info
}

Employee employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
employee->type = NULL;
employee->data = someObject;
employee->display = display;
```

Comment: By the way, why you are willing to free `NULL`?

Comment: fixed the `if(!self->type)`

Comment: If nothing else is going to free it – and that seems to be the case – you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, `type` is a member of a struct typedef-ed as `Employee`. It is a pointer to `char` pointing to dynamically allocated memory.

You indeed need to free the previous allocated memory before setting the pointer to a new value, so `free(self.type)` is fine and even required if you can call `setType` more than once.

BTW, `if (self.type)` is harmless but not required: calling `free` on a NULL pointer is required to be a no-op. Standard is clear about it and draft n1570 for C11 says at 7.22.3.3 The free function (emphasize mine):

> void free(void *ptr);
>
> Descriptionbr/>
>   2 The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. **If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs**.

So you could simply write:

```
static void setType(Employee *self, const char *type) {
    free(self->type);
    self->type = strdup(type);
}
```

But you should make sure that you initialize any instance of `Employee` with a NULL `type`...

---

To address OP's edits and gather information provided in comments:

- you shall free `type` before free-ing the containing struct (`Employee`)
- you shall not free function pointers

So `release` could be:

```
void release(Employee *self) {
    free(self->type); //  required
    //free(self->display);  DON'T
    free(self); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, another question if you don't mind. calling `free(self)` will free the whole structure including the type, no need to free to type separately? Please see the edit.

Comment: @App2015 When you free the "Employee" struct, you also need to free `self->type`.

Comment: @d3L I see, so in other words, free structure and all of it's dynamically allocated members separately (like my edit? see edit please)

Comment: @App2015 Yes. Just a note: the order in which you free is important: `free(self);` and then `free(self->type);` would be wrong.

Comment: And as Serge wrote in his answer make sure to initialize `type` with `NULL`.

Comment: sure, I understand setting type with NULL. Do I need to free function pointers (see Edit 2 please)?

Comment: @App2015 No. You only `free()` memory that has been dynamically allocated (`malloc`, `calloc` etc..)

Comment: last, let's say employee is also referencing some data object which it didn't allocated but was assigned and main program is responsible for it's free. is `self->data = NULL` within the `release` required? I've added the related piece in the code.

Comment: @App2015: C has no notion of ownership of object. You can decide to free `data` in release, but it **must** be noticed in `Employee` documentation that `data` shall have been dynamically allocated, and will be free-ed in `release`.

Comment: @App2015 It's not only not required but also pointless. You are going to free `self` on the next line. Side node: after calling `free` on a pointer the program **must** not access it later on.

Comment: Thanks Serge and @d3L.